# Atapi CallInfoChangeEvent not fired

Tags: c#, tapi

I am using the TAPI 2.0 wrapper from JulMar (https://atapi.codeplex.com/) and I'm having trouble with it.

**The Initialization**

```
void initTAPI()
    {

        myTAPI = new TapiManager("GetCaller");

        if (!myTAPI.Initialize())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("FAILED!");
        }else
        {
            name = myTAPI.Lines[0].Name;
            lineName = (myTAPI != null && myTAPI.Lines.Length > 0 ? name : string.Empty);

            foreach(TapiLine line in myTAPI.Lines)
            {
                line.NewCall += this.OnNewCall;
                line.Ringing += this.OnRinging;
                line.CallStateChanged += this.OnCallState;
                line.CallInfoChanged += this.OnCallInfo;
            }

            MessageBox.Show(lineName);

        }
    }
```

So I get the `lineName`. When I now dial a number through the program, it fires

**OnCallState**

```
private void OnCallState(object sender, CallStateEventArgs e)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired == true)
        {
            this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler<CallStateEventArgs>(this.OnCallState), new object[] { sender, e });
            return;
        }

        label1.Text = "Outgoing Call...";
    }
```

But what I actually want to do is to get the number of an incoming call, but `OnCallInfo` does not get fired.

**OnCallInfo**

```
private void OnCallInfo(object sender, CallInfoChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired == true)
        {
            this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler<CallInfoChangeEventArgs>(this.OnCallInfo), new object[] { sender, e });
            return;
        }

        label1.Text = "Incoming Call...";
    }
```

It says somehwere, that it only works with x86, so I changed the target but still no success.

PS: I have a call manager (ProCall) installed on the same machine, that tells me when someone calls, so I should be able to get the info in c# as well?

Here is the whole code if someone is interested: http://pastebin.com/Q5W5iGun

Answer (score 1):

Depending on TSP, you may get call info messages, but TAPI does not force the driver to do this. So some TSP make you get the info yourself. In the Win32 API this is done via lineGetCallInfo.

After a quick look in this atapi wrapper, this happens in the GatherCallInfo method of the TapiCall class. However I can see no way to trigger this manually in this wrapper. You would need to modify the atapi source to make this a public method.

Comment: Would you mind sharing how a `lineGetCallInfo` would look like? I am fairly new to Listeners in c# as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use example from TAPI which do the same. The only difference is new line.Monitor() method

```
foreach (TapiLine line in tapiManager.Lines)
        {
            try 
            {
                line.NewCall += OnNewCall;
                line.CallStateChanged += OnCallStateChanged;
                line.CallInfoChanged += OnCallInfoChanged;
                line.Monitor();
            }
            catch (TapiException ex)
            {
                LogError(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

For further reading read this https://atapi.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Atapi/trunk/source/test/TcMon/TapiMonitorForm.cs